# Getting the URL before making the request on AngularJS $resource module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am consuming a REST api using Angular JS, using $resource module. I have to encode the URL using a private key and send the results of the encoding process on a header. I am trying to intercept the request and getting the requested URL, but I could not do that.

```
return $resource(url, {}, {
    get: { method: 'GET', headers: headers, transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
        // Here "data" is undefined.  headersGetter() returns the headers. 
        // I need the URL here
    } 
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an interceptor. Find the **Interceptors** section of the [$http documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http). It would look something like this:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
            //modify headers in config based on url in config
            return config;
        },
    }
});
```

Then register the interceptor like this:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```